# How I use session in static funcs in mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

this line not working

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>   Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   MVC6.DNX
>   Core 5.0  26
>
> Edited
>
> i created this

```
 public class MySession
    {
        private  readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private  ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

        public  MySession(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public  void Set(string key,object o)
        {
            _session.Set(key,o);
        }

        public  void Get(string key)
        {
            var message = _session.GetString(key);
        }
    }

  public static class SessionEx
    {
        public static void Set(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);

            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

> How i use the set of session method from static func

```
  public static class SessionHandler
    { 
       public static void SetSessionId(long? id)
        {
          new MySession().Set("id", id);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The session system has been completely rewritten. In normal controllers you could just use `HttpContext.Session`, but if you need it elsewhere you need to inject it with `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Check this [blog post](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/) for more information.

Comment: In .net core 1 and 2 you'll need to configure it in startup as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184583/how-to-add-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-the-startup-class-in-the-di-in-asp-net-core-1