# How to add IHttpContextAccessor in the Startup class in the DI in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In ASP.NET Core RC 1 I used the following code to retrieve the value of context (full address of the page). Then I recorded this value in the configuration.

```
public class Startup
{
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        private IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; set; }
        private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env,
                IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {                
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
    
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    builder.AddUserSecrets();
                }
                builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration = builder.Build();
                CurrentEnvironment = env;
                HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        ...
        
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<WebAppSettings>(configuration);
        services.Configure<WebAppSettings>(settings =>
        {
            ...
            settings.WebRootPath = CurrentEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            settings.DomainUrl = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.ToUriComponent();
        });
        }
   }
```

Now I started to update the project on ASP.NET Core 1.0. But during the launch of the site I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to
> activate 'MyProject.Startup'.
>
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type type)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type type)  at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider
> services, Type startupType, string environmentName)  at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1(IServiceProvider
> sp)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryService.Invoke(ServiceProvider
> provider)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
> provider)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SingletonCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider
> provider)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(ServiceProvider
> provider)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)  at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider)  at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()  at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>
> .NET Framework X64 v4.0.30319.42000   |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
> version 1.0.0-rtm-21431   |   Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601 S

How do I get the new version IHttpContextAccessor during application startup?

Comment: If you look at the breaking changes for .Net Core, you can see that `IHttpContextAccessor` is no longer registered by default. https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It is no longer a default service. You have to configure it in Startup.cs

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

**UPDATE**: In ASP.NET Core 2.1, [the `AddHttpContextAccessor` helper extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/947) was added to correctly register the `IHttpContextAccessor` with the correct lifetime (singleton). So, in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and above, the code should be

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793

Comment: Official announcement: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190

Comment: Adding dependencies `Startap.cs` does not solve my problem because `IHttpContextAccessor` must be used in the class constructor. So I added a dependency in the `Program.cs`

Comment: one question shouldn't this be `AddTransient` because its will be for a request?

Comment: @Ruchan Did you ever get an answer for this? Should it be singleton or transient?

Comment: @Reft I used Singleton. here is more info on this https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793 read the answer by davidfowl

Comment: I am wondering why this is injected as singleton, rather than as scoped (per-request).

Comment: @Ruchan no. AddTransient would create a new instance for every service, but the HttpContext is just injected into the HttpContextAccessor once. Every other required HttpContextAccessor would not have the HttpContext.

Comment: `.AddIdentity()` is already providing the registration
https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793#issuecomment-224831136

Comment: @Ruchan Registering the `IHttpContextAccessor` as singleton works because it uses `AsyncLocal<T>` to store the HttpContext.

Comment: If you are using Dotnet 6, this is a link to the official Microsoft documentation on the topic.  Hasn't changed from this answer's recommendation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-httpcontext-from-grpc-methods

Answer (score 13):

You can add in this way for .Net 6

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add in this way.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Correct answer. You'd typically want to add that into `ConfigureServices()`.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6, without the full path gives an error, worked for me:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).