# How to make this controller's class & constructor reusable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, .net-core

```
public class AccountsMstController : Controller
{
    private AccountsMstRepository _AccountsMstRepository;
    public ErpOneLogRepository _ErpOneLogRepository;
    private DeleteRecordRepository _DeleteRecordRepository;
    private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private HttpContext _context;
    private string username;
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private string user;
    private string dbname;
    public AccountsMstController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
    IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        _context = _contextAccessor.HttpContext;
        username = _context.User.Identity.Name;
        _env = env;

        string[] Split = username.Split(new char[] { '@', '.' });
        dbname = Convert.ToString(Split[1]);
        user = Convert.ToString(Split[0]);
        _AccountsMstRepository = new AccountsMstRepository(dbname);
        _DeleteRecordRepository = new DeleteRecordRepository(dbname);
        _ErpOneLogRepository = new ErpOneLogRepository(dbname);
    }
 }
```

Trying to make this code reusable and can be called through function pointers as it is used in every Controller's class & constructors. I am trying to make this in a single method with can pass dynamic parameters and could be called from different classes.

Comment: Which part of the code are you trying to make re-usable? Also, there are no function pointers in C#!  Only delegates if that's what you mean.

Comment: I wanted to reuse ihttpContextAccessor and ihostingenviornment as a single method but it gives me error stating service cannot pass as parameter. I am trying to reuse because my every controller calls this implementation!

Comment: I was trying to create a single class that would implement ihttpContextAccessor and ihostingenviornment but it gave me error that service cannot be passed as paramter while instantiating.

Comment: Ok. And I see your using .NET Core. have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184583/how-to-add-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-the-startup-class-in-the-di-in-asp-net-core-1. Although it might not be relevant if you've no DI.

Comment: I've not used Core yet to be honest. But you could also just make each controller instance the interface in a parameter less constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would start of with using an interface:

```
public interface IController {
    HttpContext Context{get; set; }
    string Username {get; set; }
    IHostingEnvironment Environment {get; set; }
    string User {get; set; }
    string DbName {get; set; }
    UnitOfWork ControllerWork {get; set;}
}
```

Assuming the repositories contain a DbContext object you could use the Repository - UnitOfWork pattern

```
public interface UnitOfWorkFactory {
    AccountsMstRepository AccountsMstRepository {get; set;}
    ErpOneLogRepository ErpOneLogRepository get; set;}
    DeleteRecordRepository DeleteRecordRepository {get; set;}
    DbContext DbContext {get; set;}

    // CRUD methods to update repository
}

public interface RepositoryFactory {
    DbContext context {get; set;}

    // CRUD methods to update repository
}
```

This way each different controller can implement the IController interface, so you can access the repositories on each controller using the intermediary UnitOfWork (you need to make a class that implements this)

If you want to make this even more reusable and you are using the Entity Framework you can use a BaseModel and implement the RepositoryFactory using basetype T, this way your UnitOfWorkFactory will not get cluttered. But for this, this is alright.

Here's a link on the pattern: [microsoft-uow pattern implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Hoping to have answered your question.

Joachim.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a BaseController class with constructor accepting IHttpContextAccessor and IHostingEnvironment and have all controllers inherit from it ?

Comment: I tried doing so, in order to invoke i need to pass parameter to the base controller which has IHttpContextAccessor and IHostingEnviornment soo it gave an error saying service cannot be passed as paramters eg : BaseController B =new BaseController(IHttpContextAccessor, IHostingEnviornment)