# Get explicit url entered in browser with asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application that uses ReactJS on the client and would like to log the urls entered explicitly in the browser for tracking purposes.  For example, I would like to know when a user explicitly enters: http://myapp.com/; http://myapp.com/contact; http://myapp.com/help; etc... in the browser.  I'm able to track when a user clicks on various links once they're already in http://myapp.com using Javascript, but it's when a user enters it directly in the browser (or clicks on a link from a google search) that I'm currently unable to track.

I've been looking at url middleware rewrite as well as trying to find a way to access the HttpContext from something like ConfigureServices in the Startup class, but I'm not able to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using the `IHttpContextAccessor`: e.g. `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value`; [Register it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186047/2477619) via: `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing Middleware is fairly straight forward, adapting the example slightly from [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) will log the URL.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var logger = new MyLogger();
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path;
    logger.Log(requestPath);
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

However, I don't think it's possible to discern from the `HttpContext` whether the URL was entered in the browser address bar, versus any old GET request.

Comment: Like you mentioned, this grabs and logs every request.  Will need to figure out a way to just get the browser url entered, or at least filter it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for Referer Headers. Asp.Net Core has an http extension library which has an extension method to get the typed headers.

Add this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

Then access the Referer using the GetTypedHeaders() extension on a HttpContext, these are some of the properties:

```
httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer.AbsolutePath
httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer.AbsoluteUri
httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer.Authority
httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer.Host
httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Referer.PathAndQuery
```

Say our Refering Url is like:

```
http://localhost:4200/profile/users/1?x=1
```

The above properties will have these values:

```
/profile/users/1
http://localhost:4200/profile/users/1?x=1
localhost:4200
localhost
/profile/users/1?x=1
```