# Access user claim after login in asp.net core

Tags: c#

I need access User.Claims with in separate class and inside a static method in asp.net core.Is there any solution.

```cs
User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value
```

Comment: public int UserId()
        {
           var user= accessor.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;
           return Convert.ToInt32(user);
     }

I need this kind of solution

Comment: So basically you created the same question again? [Access User.Claims in Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035913/access-user-claims-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: yes i need a solution

Comment: You should not ask duplicate question. you need to update your existing!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access User.Claims in Asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035913/access-user-claims-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: If there a reason that it is a static method? You cannot get it in a static method, you have to pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass an instance of `IHttpContextAccessor` to your static method or class, either through dependency injection or directly.

Make sure to [register the accessor as a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38184583/993547):

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

From there on, you can access `accessor.HttpContext.User`.

Comment: can you share any example for this

Comment: There is in my answer.

Comment: answer is not related to the  questions

Comment: public int UserId() { var user= User.Identity.Name; return Convert.ToInt32(user);       In here User is not in current context  .How to fix it

Comment: So where in that code is `accessor.HttpContext.User`?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class BLLBaseClass
   {
       private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
       public BLLBaseClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
       {
           this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
       }

       public int UserId
       {
           get
           {
               var value = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User?.Claims?.First(c => c.Type == "UserId").Value;
               if (Int32.TryParse(value, out int userId))
               {
                   return userId;
               }

               return 0;
           }
       }
   }
```

Inherit that class and you can access directly userid

```
 public class GeneralBLL : BLLBaseClass
    {
        private readonly GeneralDAL _generalDal;

        public GeneralBLL(GeneralDAL generalDal, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _generalDal = generalDal;
        }

        public List<Department> GetDepartments()
        {
            var userId = UserId;
            try
            {
                return _generalDal.GetDepartments();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw new Exception("unable to get departments.");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your startup.cs file you need to register the service first by adding the following

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<TestClass>();
```

Then you should register your class where you want to access the claims from so that we can inject IActionContextAcessor into.

```
public class TestClass
{
     private IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor;
     public Test(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
     {
         this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
     }

     public void GetClaims()
     {
        var claims = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.User.Claims;
        return claims;
     }
 }
```

Now you can inject this class anywhere you want to access the users claims.
Of course you can also just inject IActionContextAccessor into any class as well if you just simply need to get the claims.

So inside the constructor of your class for example you can say

```
public class MyCustomClass
{
   private TestClass testClass;
   public MyCustomClass(TestClass testClass)
   {
      this.testClass = testClass;
   }

   public void MyMethod()
   {
      var usersClaims = this.testClass.GetClaims();
   }
}
```

Hope that helps
SoS

Comment: how to access it from other class .share your answer with code

Comment: HrmContext.GetClaims(); i need this kind of a solution

Comment: You just inject that class to wherever you need it. I have edited the answer to include that bit as well

Answer (score 0):

I would stronlgy advise staying away from static class implementation for accessing `HttpContext`.

When you need user identifier in your classes just inject `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public class CustomService
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void CustomMethod()
    {
        var userId = this.httpContextAccessor.GetUserId();
        // do what you want with user identifier
    }
}
```

For this code to work you'll need extension method

```
public static class HttpContextAccessorExtensions
{
    public static int GetUserId(this IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        var value = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User?.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value, out int userId))
        {
            return userId;
        }

        return 0; // or whatever you want if userId is not found (I would suggest making return type int? and returning null here)

    }
}
```

Also you'll need to add this to your `Startup.cs` inside `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```