# Dependency injected IHttpContextAccessor is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

When I try to call this service and the method GetOrganization() within the http context accessor is null. What could cause the problem?

```
public class ShopService
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor? _httpContextAccessor;

    public ShopService(IHttpContextAccessor? httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public static async Task<Organization?> GetOrganization(EnvironmentType environment)
    {
             string? accessToken;
            if (_httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext != null)
            {
                accessToken = GetToken();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    
            // ... other unimportant code
    }
}
```

This calls the method from the service:

```
                Organization = User?.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.AuthenticationType switch
                {
                    "Google" => ShopService.GetOrganization(EnvironmentType.Google).Result,
                    // other unimportant code
                    };
```

I have this in startup:
`builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
`builder.Services.AddScoped<ShopService>();`

Am I missing something why does it not work?
Am I supposed to add something in startup, other than the ShopService
service?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: What is this being injected into? Please also show you DI setup. It's preferable to paste in code rather than screenshots so others can replicate the problem.

Comment: What framework are you targeting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add IHttpContextAccessor in the Startup class in the DI in ASP.NET Core 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184583/how-to-add-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-the-startup-class-in-the-di-in-asp-net-core-1)

Comment: Maybe because it's `static`?

Comment: @SpruceMoose I don't understand what 'what is this being injected into' means, I update the question with code

Comment: @haim770 it has to be static

Comment: @gunr2171 I am using .net core, developing a blazor app

Comment: @madreflection how do I change this and not be static, how do I call the method from the service then?

Comment: @MatejDodevski, If it has to be `static` then you can't expect it to be set using the constructor (that probably wasn't event called when you merely do `GetOrganization()`). You better pass it as an argument it to the `GetOrganization()` method itself, possibly after resolving it manually in the callsite.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all your suggestions. I removed the 'static' from the method and added this wherever I needed the service `@inject ShopService _shopService`

Comment: IHttpContextAccessor should not be used in Blazor apps according to [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state)